# Is it possible to change the value of environment variable from a bash script so that it persists?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I would like to use an environment variable I have declared in `/etc/environment` as a counter which should be accessible to several unrelated scripts that are run at different times.

Is that possible? So far, I had no luck trying exporting its value.

I guess, I could always use a temporary file to store current value, read/write to it but I'm looking for a more elegant way if there is any?

Comment: What happens if two scripts try to change the counter simultaneously? I’d rather use a *file* which contains the counter value and lock it as explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184259/246819).

Comment: `mktemp` is elegance in its purest form. ;)

Comment: The issue probably isn't *persistence* - it's that the other scripts will need to re-source their environment for any modified value to take effect

Comment: Good point, but I'd take care that doesn't happen. I agree, using a file instead is a way to achieve the same although, what happens if two scripts try to change the value in the file simultaneously ;) I'm mostly asking to improve my understanding of how environment is working. And it would be wonderful if it is somehow possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No, you can't permanently change an environment variable from within a Bash script".

The longer answer is that when a Bash script is executed it receives a *copy* of the environment (not references to the environment variables themselves). So, whilst you can change the values of the *copies* within your script, those changes will be lost when the script exits *and* are also not visible to other scripts you may be running concurrently.

You *can* however, change an environment variable with a Bash script by "source"-ing it from the command line:

```
source  your_script_name
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I just took a look at "source-ing" and it doesn't cut it for this purpose. I need to pass a variable from a Nemo script to a script that is executed by an applet so, the only viable way seems to be the use of a temporary file as dessert pinpointed.

Answer (score 1):

The changes will not be absolutely permanent but you can keep the changes to the environment variable as long as you are in the same login shell from which you executed the script.

---

There are multiple commands to execute a shell script, each command has it's own way to execute it.
If you ran the script using the dot(.) operator, the script is executed within the same shell instead of opening another shell for the execution.

> . myscript.sh

Hence, the changes to the environment variable made in that script will persist as long as it is executed using dot(.) and the shell from which it was executed is not closed.